# Simple PHP: getting variable from a form input

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

I can't really use PHP and from what I've seen in tutorials this should work, but it doesn't:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type='text' name="name" value='myName'>
    </form>
    <p>
      <?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo $name
      ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason I can't get the value of name?
Sorry for asking such a simple question...

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DCmu5/1/, so, please try what you said and send it to me only when it works before answering

Comment: Add an `<input type="submit" value="Go" />` and modify the for to POST method (`<form method="POST">=), submit the form, then it should be visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, so you'll need to submit the form in order to access its variables.

Since you didn't specify a `method`, `GET` is assumed, so you'll need the `$_GET` super-global:

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

It's probably better though, to use `$_POST` (since it'll avoid the values being passed in the URL directly. As such, you can add `method` attribute to your `<form>` element as follows:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type='text' name="name" value="myName" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Notice I also added a submit button for good measure, but this isn't required. Simply hitting return inside the textbox would submit the form.

Comment: I tried that too... you mean <form method='POST'>, right? didn't work

Comment: Well, it should. Are you sure you're actually submitting the form?

Comment: look at the fiddle and try it yourself: doesn't work! http://jsfiddle.net/DCmu5/1/

Comment: Are you serious? Of course it doesn't work on jsFiddle... PHP code needs executing on a server, a proper server. Not jsFiddle.

Comment: ok, I'll try on my server and tell you how it goes, even tho I think I've already tried

Comment: that's not my final code, was just wanting to understand how to do it... but still, I can't see any typo, what are you referring to?

Comment: This > `$ _POST[ 'name'];`. There's superfluous space after `$`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45022/discussion-between-cicada3301-and-benm)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to POST your form to get the value of `$_POST` variables. Add this to your `<form>`

```
<form action="yourpagename.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' name="name" value='myName'>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Click button and whatever is typed in your field will show up.

Comment: wow... is it possible that such a simple question which should be at the basics of PHP isn't answerable?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="1.php">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  $name = $_POST['fname'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    echo "Name is empty";
  } else {
    echo $name;
  }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
                echo $name;
    }
     ?>
```