# How to get form input data from a website into a file or some place useful?

Tags: javascript, php

I need some general help on what tools to use.  I was a programmer so I know how programming works, but I'm wildly out of touch.

So I have a website.  On it, I've added input form fields (name, address, etc.) I'll put the code below.

I need to know what language/tool to use to get those inputs sent to a file that will be easy to check, or better yet, sent to an email address.  Someone other than me will be keeping that member info.  So I need them to easily have access to it.

I've looked briefly at PHP and JavaScript, but before I spend weeks reading... can you tell me what tool, and a basic idea of how to do it, and great would be a reference to a w3schools page that covers this topic.

So far for gathering data off the site I'm using:

```
<form ACTION="play_form.php" method="post" 
 target="_top" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-
 urlencoded" autocomplete="on" novalidate>  

 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 Areas of interest: <input type="text" name="areas"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

I want to use post, not get.  I'll turn on validation after I figure the basics out.  I have no idea what type of file to put into action field.

Nor what to put into that file I create. (Such as what w3 reference to use to figure it out).

So far I tried out the http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp sample and it works on Firefox, but when I copy the code to my own website file (currently on my own computer), it doesn't work.  It displays the straight text "My first PHP page" but not the "welcome world" input text.  It did the same in IE.

Thanks for any guidance!

---

This is a low money non-profit.  We don't have servers.  I just need people to be able to pay membership with paypal and at the same time add various info about themselves that we can then gather and store in our offline private database.  There is no ongoing need for them to access that data again.

I should have included this originally.

---

Edit for suggested answer:

That answer had some relevant info and helped solve why my php wasn't printing the passed through input form data.  It needed a name="something" given to the submit line.

It didn't answer to the rest of the problem, that I can see so far.

At this point I've figured out a bunch.  I probably could get the input forms into an SQL database with some more work.  That helps me know how all of this is connected, so I know where to look for what code is needed for each step of the process.  It appears PHP does not have an email, nor write to file and send option... (which makes sense that it doesn't.)

However what I need is the input forms data to be sent in email and then discarded from the website.  I'm working on that now and have a few sites googled to look at.

This page appears to have what I'm looking for namely PHP ways to email data in clear description.  It uses a PHP mail() function.
http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/

I've also found code for how to add a button that let's the buyer set the dollar amount then put it into a paypal cart.  You can't do that on the paypal account create buttons area.  I've tested and it works!
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Can-you-create-an-Open-Amount-PayPal-button/td-p/651509

So cool, I went from no idea what tools to use, to all the bits and pieces solved, and now just have to work on how to string them together for specifically what I want (and have to learn error checking in these tools to add that code too.)  Yay!! Thank you!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple PHP: getting variable from a form input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067575/simple-php-getting-variable-from-a-form-input)

Comment: Based on questions - here's additional info that matters!
.......................................
This is a low money non-profit. We don't have servers. I just need people to be able to pay membership with paypal and at the same time add various info about themselves that we can then gather and store in our offline private database. There is no ongoing need for them to access that data again.
......................................
The website is hosted by hostgator and Wild West domains. They support PHP, so from what I see on the w3 tutorial, I don't need any server side set up

Comment: That last bit of problem was solved by adding <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"  (in other words adding name="go") to the input form.  Now the input is being displayed in the output file listed (play_form.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the input data using XAMPP MYSQL.

Languages you will most likely use maybe SQL and PHP.

ALso, you can use isset() function to 'transfer' the input into your MYSQL database.

For example, based on your form. we can create a database called myDB.

In myDB, we can create a table called 'user'.

From there, we can create columns for the table: fname,lname, interests.

You can refer to  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAXhXI2Gxdc on how to create database and tables.

Next we can  insert the data input using the code below.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","myDB"); //connect to database
if (!$connect){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno()); //return error is connect fail
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fname= $_POST['fname'];
$lname= $_POST['lname'];
$areas= $_POST['areas'];

$query= $con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO user(fname,lname,areas) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$query -> bind_param("sss",$fname,$lname,$areas );

if ($query->execute())
    {
        echo"<center><strong>User added! </strong></center>";
    } // display when user is added
        else{
            echo"Error in adding user!"; // display when there is error
        }
}


?>
```

Here are some useful information you can refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/

Comment: Suppko & anyone else --- alternatively is there a way to connect and put this into a text file or excel (or googlespread sheet) file?  I don't have sql on my computer that I can see, and would have to get to other people to install it too.  As I look, maybe I'll see how to do it...!

Comment: SQL is provided by my webhost, turns out.  So now I have to work on getting inputs to the SQL database I created (no rows or cols yet)... and I still am hoping to email inputs, and avoid storing them in a database online.

Comment: Welcome. On the email inputs.. that is out of my reach as I only know how to store them in a MYSQL database. If that was helpful to you, remember to click on the tick beside the answer!

Comment: Suppko - turns out sending the inputs in an email is easy.  There's a PHP mail() command.  So same way it's sent to sql, it can be sent to an email.  The 3w.school site described it.  For some very odd reason it's not on their main page about PHP nor is there mention of more functions available beyond their main page.  To me input/output methods from a function are top priority to know about...

Comment: ah.. I've misunderstood your question.. sending the input to email is pretty simple. I've just done it last week for my project. I would prefer using PHPMailer as it's much simpler once you understand how to use it.

Comment: Another function phpmailer?  I'll go look for it on 3w and see if it works better for my application.  Now I just have to figure out how to format the pages... namely if I use input form to collect basic data, then have a bunch of buttons with additional data collected specific to each one, can I put this into separate html or php files, and carry the input values forward so I can then send to paypal and email.  In other words, have to figure out the scope of the variables filled by the input data and how to store them to use in phps.