# Change php variable with html button

Tags: javascript

now this is my html button

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button type="button">change header</button>
</div
</body></html>
```

> what i want is when i click on it change the variable

example

```
<?php

$var= "path1";
$new= "path2";

if ( some one clicked the button) !== false) {
$var = $new;
header('Location: $var');

} else {
header('Location: $var');

}
?>
```

if there is a method with javascript please post it please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple PHP: getting variable from a form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067575/simple-php-getting-variable-from-a-form-input)

Comment: didnt get it clear... do you have form tag in html. if u wont use form tage its not possible by php.

Comment: @mdus2r no not the same purpose

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can try the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" value="t">
   <button>change header</button>   
</form>
```

Add the post check to see if the page is posted.

```
<?php

$var= "hello world";
$new= "i hate world";

if ( $_POST ) {
    $var= $new;
    echo $var;
} else {
    echo $var;
}
```

But my guess is that you're really looking for a JS way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button type="button" onClick="function()">change header</button>
</div>
</body></html>
```

```js
function(){
$var= "hello world";
$new= "i hate world";


    $var= $new;
    echo $var;

 echo $var;
}
```

Php is a server side language. You can use javascript like this or if you really want to use php you need to submit the form

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with this, but that's definitely not JavaScript LOL.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side so it is executed before the page/html is sent to the user. any user interactions are handled by Javascript in the browser. 
if you wish to change content when a user clicks a button the use javascript event handlers

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeStuff()">change header</button>
</div>
<script>
    function changeStuff(){
        //change header code
    }
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: shoud i use js or phh ?

Comment: use javascript to handle user interactions like button clicks, hover and such. use php for server side stuff like when a form is submitted or before page is sent to users

Answer (score 0):

reko beko@@ see this is hundred percent working

```
  <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" value="t">
       <input type="submit" value="change header" name="submit">
    </form>

<?php

$var= "hello world";
$new= "i hate world";

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $var= $new;
    echo $var;
} else {
    echo $var;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
            <head>
        <script>
              function  myfunction(){
         // no variable needed for this logic

           //window.location.replace('the redirect path when button is clicked ')
           // example 
          window.location.replace('newsletter_tb.php');

            }
    </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>

            <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">change header</button>
            </div
            </body>
        </html>
```

- Using javascript is best for this question
- PHP is server side scripting language

Comment: should i use js or php ?

Comment: @rekobeko Yeah if i may say. because are not posting it to database or processing it to database. But on the other hand Javascript is good for this kind of example.

Comment: Please do not use the `>` character for personal formatting, [this has been discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355183/1415724) - I had to edit that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button type="button" id="chnageHeaderbtn">change header</button>
```

Put in script

```
$("#chnageHeaderbtn").click(function() { 
var prevUrlAddress='http://www.myfirsturl.com';
var chnageUrlAddress='http://www.myurl.com';

window.location.href =chnageUrlAddress;

});
```